# Client side problems with recvfrom function

Tags: c, sockets, udp

Hu guys,

I'm stuck with this problem a long time, please help ! I have server on one laptop which is sending data to client on another laptop,same lan. I can see udp packets on wireshark on server side and also on client side... But the problem is in code, the client is just stuck on line " printf("Opening datagram socket....OK.\n");"  Why the code does'nt working to printf received buf from server ? As I said, packets are visible in wireshark what confuses me :S

Any advice please...

```
int main(){

struct sockaddr_in srv_addr;
int sd,fd,datalen,numRead;
ssize_t nbytes,numWrite;
socklen_t addrlen=sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
char buf[MAX_SIZE],tmp[MAX_SIZE];


if((sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0))<0){
    printf("Opening datagram socket error",strerror(errno));
    return 1;

}else{
    printf("Opening datagram socket....OK.\n");
}

memset((char *) &srv_addr, 0, sizeof(srv_addr));
srv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
srv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT_NUM);
srv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IP_SERVER);
memset(buf,0,MAX_SIZE);

while(1){

   nbytes = recvfrom(sd,buf,MAX_SIZE,0,(struct sockaddr *)&srv_addr, &addrlen);

    if(nbytes != -1){

        printf("The %s message from server\n",buf);


}else{

    printf("Recvfrom error %s\n",strerror(errno));    

}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Your code misses a closing brace (`}`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `bind()` call.

```
bind(sd, (SOCKADDR*) &srv_addr, sizeof (srv_addr));
```

bind is always necessary on both ends, otherwise your socket wouldn't know what port/interface it is operating on.

Also, you have to bind your Socket to an interface on your local computer. `srv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IP_SERVER);` defines the interface, identified by its IP, the Socket is bound to and listening on. If you want to limit Communication partners you have to check the sockaddr struct returned by recvfrom (5th parameter)

replace `inet_addr(IP_SERVER)` with `htonl(INADDR_ANY)`. Which will tell your socket to listen on every interface available on your local computer.

Comment: Great, it solved the problem, thank you. I thought that bind is enough just on server side, I'm new with sockets...but when I add bind and change address to INADDR_ANY it works perfect ! Thanks again

Comment: As you are new to socket programming I added some further explanation. I hope this will help you understand what's going on.